# 301 redirect rewrite query string in .htaccess

Tags: htaccess, 301-redirect, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, query-string

I am trying to perform a 301 redirect in .htaccess and I need to remove the query string `?view=full`. Here is what I have that is not working:

```
RewriteRule ^/contact/?view=full$ /contact/ [R=301,L]
```

I have tried a variety of different solutions with no luck.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
> RewriteRule ^/contact/?view=full$ /contact/ [R=301,L]
> ```

The `RewriteRule` *pattern* matches against the URL-path only, which notably excludes the query string. So, the above directive won't match the required URL. To match the query string you need to use an additional condition and check against the `QUERY_STRING` server variable.

Also, in `.htaccess` (*directory* context) the URL-path matched by the `RewriteRule` *pattern* does not start with a slash, because the directory-prefix that is first removed from the URL that is matched by the *pattern* ends with a slash. So, again, the directive will not match the requested URL because of the slash prefix.

Also, the query string from the request is copied through to the substitution string by default - unless you explicitly *discard* or create a new query string. So, the above directive won't remove the query string either.

Try the following instead, near the top of your `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^view=full$
RewriteRule ^(contact/)$ /$1 [QSD,R=302,L]
```

This matches the URL `/contact/?view=full` exactly. And redirects to `/contact/`. The `QSD` (Query String Discard) flag (Apache 2.4) on the `RewriteRule` directive *discards* the query string from the *substitution* string.

The `$1` is a backreference to the captured group in the `RewriteRule` *pattern*, ie. the value `contact/`. This simply saves typing/repetition.

Note that this is currently a 302 (temporary) redirect. If this is intended to be permanent then only change it to a 301 once you have tested that it works OK. 301s are cached persistently by the browser, so can make testing problematic.

You should clear your browser cache before testing.

Reference:

- https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule